# Why is 'metrics = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()' giving an error but 'metrics=['accuracy']' isn't?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Im using the given code example on the fashion_mnist dataset. It contains `metrics="accuracy"` and runs through. Whenever I change it to `metrics=tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()` it gives me following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (32, 10) and (32, 1) are incompatible
```

What am i doing wrong? Is the `Accuracy()` function not the same?

```
import tensorflow as tf

fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images / 255.
test_images = test_images / 255.

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)])

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile):

> When you pass the strings `"accuracy"` or `"acc"`, we convert this to one of `tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy`, `tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy`, `tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy` based on the loss function used and the model output shape.

So, when you pass `"accuracy"` it will be converted to the `SparseCategoricalAccuracy()` automatically.

So you can pass it like following:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
# or
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy'])
```